# What's the difference between IMPORT-MODULE and PREBUILTS?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, import-module

Currently I'm using ffmpeg to develop a media player on Android. I've compiled ffmpeg using ndk. And next I have to use the built module to code. So here comes the question: how to use the compiled ffmpeg?

Firstly I thought since I have to import the ffmpeg module, I have to read `$(ndk)/docs/IMPORT-MODULE.html`. But when it came to practice, things didn't work out.

After a time of struggling, I found there's docs called `PREBUILTS.html`, which was exactly what I want. So I built a new project, copy `libffmpeg.so` to `$(newProject)/jni` and write `Android.mk` step by step as the docs depicted. It hasn't worked fine yet, but I believe I've found the right way.

So here comes the question: What's the difference between `IMPORT-MODULE` and `PREBUILTS`? Does `IMPORT-MODULE` means that the imported module could work itself (could be distributed as binary), and `PREBUILTS` means it's only a dynamic library?